# KivyMD: Access MDList id from a screen of Navigation Layout

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I'm trying to access the id:container in my main.py but I can't seem to find the right input. Here is my main.py

```
class ScreenFive(Screen):
  def on_start(self):
    for i in range(20):
        self.ids.screen_manager2.classes.container.add_widget(
            OneLineListItem(text=f"Single-line item {i}")
        )
```

Here is my main.kv file

```
<ScreenFive>
name: 'home'
FitImage:
    source: 'Media/home_bg.png'
BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    MDToolbar:
        title: 'QR Attendance'
        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
        elevation:5
    Widget:
NavigationLayout:
    ScreenManager:
        id: screen_manager2
        Screen:
            name: 'classes'
            MDCard:
                orientation: "vertical"
                padding: "8dp"
                size_hint: None, None
                size: "280dp", "400dp"
                pos_hint: {"center_x": .5, "center_y": .5}
                ripple_behavior: True
                focus_behavior: True
                md_bg_color: self.theme_cls.bg_light

                ScrollView:
                    MDList:
                        id: container
```

What should I do to access the MDList in my screen "classes"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that everything after `<ScreenFive>:` in your `kv` is indented (so it is all inside `ScreenFive`), then I think you can replace:

```
self.ids.screen_manager2.classes.container
```

with:

```
self.ids.container
```